# Why can't I found the implementation of _Unwind_Backtrace in android open source project of kitkat?

Tags: android-source, stack-trace, android-4.4-kitkat, callstack

I am reading the code about the implementation of printing stack trace in native code of android, I found the following code:

```
ssize_t unwind_backtrace(backtrace_frame_t* backtrace, size_t ignore_depth, size_t max_depth) {
    ALOGV("Unwinding current thread %d.", gettid());

    map_info_t* milist = acquire_my_map_info_list();

    backtrace_state_t state;
    state.backtrace = backtrace;
    state.ignore_depth = ignore_depth;
    state.max_depth = max_depth;
    state.ignored_frames = 0;
    state.returned_frames = 0;
    init_memory(&state.memory, milist);

    _Unwind_Reason_Code rc = _Unwind_Backtrace(unwind_backtrace_callback, &state);

    release_my_map_info_list(milist);

    if (state.returned_frames) {
        return state.returned_frames;
    }
    return rc == _URC_END_OF_STACK ? 0 : -1;
}
```

but I can't find the implementation of `_Unwind_Backtrace` in http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/ , is there any body konw the reason? Where is the implementation of `_Unwind_Backtrace`?

Answer (score 0):

For android 4.4, `unwind_backtrace` is in `/system/core/libcorkscrew/backtrace.c`

Comment: I rechecked the `system/core/libcorkscrew/backtrace.c`, there is no definition of `_Unwind_Backtrace` but just a function call `_Unwind_Reason_Code rc = _Unwind_Backtrace(unwind_backtrace_callback, &state);`.

Comment: @cong http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/system/core/libcorkscrew/backtrace.c#80

Comment: Then what does `_Unwind_Backtrace` do? Is `_Unwind_Backtrace` a macro or something?

Comment: @cong I did not find the macro, I guess there's a lib which implement _Unwind_Backtrace symbol but the source is not in AOSP. I don't have the AOSP 4.4, but if I have, I can use `nm` to find out the lib in out dir and get a clue further.

Comment: I think you are wrong, I decompiled the `libcorkscrew.so`, the implementation of `_Unwind_Backtrace` is in `libcorkscrew.so`, but I can't find the implementation in source level throughout the AOSP.

Comment: @cong why I'm wrong? libcorkscrew.so is in /prebuilts/sdk/tools/xxx/bin, the lib is prebuilt and placed in the the AOSP project, so there's no source code. Isn't this what I talking about?

Comment: The source code of `libcorkscrew.so` is in `system/core/libcorkscrew` of aosp. I wonder if the implementation of `_Unwind_Backtrace` is in compiler, I am not familiar with the aosp build chain, so, I can't find the clue.

Comment: @cong I don't think so, compiler only defines some attributes, the `_Unwind_Backtrace` here is definitely an identifier. There are cases that one lib is not built from the source code in AOSP, especially libs in /prebuilts dir.

Comment: @cong look at this https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libgcc/unwind.inc, this is the implementation of _Unwind_Backtrace by gcc. libcorkscrew.so probably build from code like this and placed in the AOSP project.

Comment: I rechecked the prebuilds directory, and found out that the implementation of  `_Unwind_Backtrace` may be in `prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/x86/i686-linux-android-4.7/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.7/libgcc.a`.